# Can ISP detect a proxy connection's contents?

Tags: networking, proxy

No idea if this is right place to ask.

In my country, by law, all ISPs are required to block certain websites. People can not access such sites. But, through proxy websites every one can access blocked websites. I guess the flow is `My PC ---> My ISP ---> Proxy ---> Website` and then it returns back the same path.

If all the Internet resources are requested through the ISP, then why can't they detect a disallowed website being requested via a proxy site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ISPs can know what's in the requested resource. But, proxy sites usually encrypt all the information so ISP don't know what's inside.

Also, ISPs handle so huge amount of traffic that they do not keep spying on the content they transfer until required by legislature.